# how to multiple spread operator inside map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {

  state = {
    item: [{fruit: 'apple'}]
  }

  handle=(name, value, num)=>{
    console.log(name, value, num)

    this.setState(({item}) => ({
        item: item.map((cv,i)=>( {...cv, [name]: {[num] :value}})
    )
    }), ()=>{ console.log(this.state.item)})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Input name={'items'} onChange={this.handle}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

A working example: https://jsfiddle.net/dapyb0ef/

`item: item.map((cv,i)=>( {...cv, [name]: {[num] :value}})`

each time I type in a field, it will overwrite the previous one. so it prints only one item in `items` e.g.

```
fruit: "apple"
items: {2: "123"}
```

What I am achieving is to keep all items when typing in each input field

```
   fruit: "apple"
   items: {0: "typed string..."}, {1: "typed information"}, {2: "typed information"}
```

So my question is  `item: item.map((cv,i)=>( {...cv, [name]: {[num] :value}})`
How do i store `[num]` and keep all information. Thanks

Comment: why you are not doing it as a form with a submit button ?? do you have specific need to become like this ?? because it doesn't make sense ?

Comment: Just an example for testing! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to spread the inner items as well like

```
 this.setState(({item}) => ({
    item: item.map((cv,i)=>( {...cv, [name]: {...cv[name], [num] :value}})
)
```

**[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/71vzobrL/)**

Answer (score 1):

what you're doing is spreading cv then overriding his `items` property completely, you forgot to spread the existing `cv.items` content

```
{item: item.map((cv,i)=>( {...cv, [name]: {...cv[name], [num] :value}})}
```